# Specifying a return type for Slick's MappedProjection

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, slick

I'm using the PlayFramework 2.1.1 in combination with Slick 1.0.1 and the Play-Slick-Plugin 0.3.2.

Defining an abstract class that enforces my models to implement a "forInsert"-Mapper fails because I'm unable to specify the proper return type. My current definition results in the compile error below but I'm simply unable to track down this issue and provide the correct type.

```
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.KeysInsertInvoker

abstract class Model[M]( val table: String ) extends Table[M]( table )
{
    def id = column[Int]( "id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc )

    def forInsert: KeysInsertInvoker[M, Int]
}
```

---

```
object Course extends Model[Course]( "course" )
{
    ...

    def forInsert = name ~ room <> ( apply _, unapply _ ) returning id
}
```

---

```
[error] Course.scala:27: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : [RU]play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.KeysInsertInvoker[model.Course,RU]
[error]  required: play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.KeysInsertInvoker[model.Course,Int]
[error]         def forInsert = name ~ room <> ( apply _, unapply _ ) returning id
[error]                                                               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (sample/compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 18.06.2013 03:38:24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abstract class Model[M]( val table: String ) extends Table[M]( table )
{
    def id = column[Int]( "id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc )

    def forInsert: scala.slick.driver.BasicInvokerComponent#KeysInsertInvoker[M, Int]
}
```

Not that difficult. Printing a `getClass` from the implementation solved the mystery quite easily. An idea I didn't come up with yesterday night.